# Postgres SQL - Sum rolling 24 hour weight for each row

Tags: postgresql

I have a table where I have date delivered, and weight.
I need to add a column for the "24 hour aggregate" - looking forward 12 hours and looking backward 12 hours for each row, and totaling the weight. Sort of a 12 hour rolling throughput of weight.

Here is what I tried, but doesn't work/return anything:

```
select delivered_time, 
       (select  Sum(Gross_Weight) 
       from loads_table  
       where delivered_time > delivered_time - interval '12 hours' 
         and delivered_time < delivered_time + interval '12 hours') as sumweight 
from loads_table 
group by delivered_time
```

I tried a couple of different queries, but new to SQL, Postgres, etc... and having a hard time. I'm somewhat of an excel jockey.

So - I need to sum the weight for the previous 12 hours, and trailing 12 hours for each row, and stick it in a column called "sumweight"

Answer (score 1):

Are you maybe looking for a rolling sum window function?

```
select <other columns>,
       sum(gross_weight) over (order by delivered_time range between '12 hours' preceding and '12 hours' following) as sumweight
from loads_table
order by delivered_time;
```

Comment: That seems to be moving in the right direction a_horse_with_no_name, but when I use the query you suggested above - I get an error:
SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: RANGE PRECEDING is only supported with UNBOUNDED

Not sure what that means, but if you could suggest a tweak, I'd greatly appreciate it.